# Why text is not displayed in the center of a button?

Tags: android, android-layout

XML:

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnRecord"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="●"
                    android:textColor="#C63E3B"
                    android:textSize="40sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="▶"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="40sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnS"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="■"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="40sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Result of above code design by graphical layout is:
[image]

But, when I run on real phone , it is not displayed at the center:
[image]

Why text is not being displayed at the center of button?

Comment: show us your `MainActivity.java` file??

Comment: file MainActivity.java : only set btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
  btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
  btnPlay.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#777777"));

Comment: @mum, you can explore its `onDraw` method. Guess the baseline is different when you're displaying a special char

Answer (score 1):

You can see that `play` sign is centered but `cirle` or `rectangle` are not. This is because this `sign` is not centered sign in this font. (try to highlight "■" this sign in your browser and see that on the bottom is less space than at the top)

Use images instead.

Answer (score 0):

its better to use images of same dimentions rather than special charz. Also try to declare clickable TextView with gray bg color instead of buttons just to see what gonna happen:

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/btnRecord"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="●"
                    android:textColor="#C63E3B"
                    android:textSize="40sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="▶"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="40sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/btnS"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="■"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="40sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

also you could use drawables shapes declared in xml to make circle, rectangle etc.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that your "play" button is in a different `drawable` folder than the other two buttons, because it looks a little smaller. Try to check it out.